# HTML tags with class="spoken" being displayed

Tags: internet-explorer-8, accessibility

I'm attempting to make a site Section 508 compliant. I've got `<span class="spoken">` for some headers to hide the text and make it readable by screen readers.

But the text is displaying on IE8.

Is there a way to hide it? Or should I be using some ARIA label?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's an article about "Using aria-label to provide an invisible label", but I guess that IE8 is dead anyway.

http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-label_to_provide_an_invisible_label

Comment: Where are you getting the class "spoken" from? - From looking at bootstrap docs, looks like "sr-only" it the name of its utility class for this purpose.

Comment: You should be able to inspect the `span` element itself with the [Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565627(v=vs.85).aspx) and see the specific rules that are causing it to render differently, or not at all.

Comment: It would help if you provided a snippet of HTML and the relevant CSS. A link to the website where this is happening, or an example using something like JSfiddle or JSbin.